# minimal nginx installation from source?

Tags: nginx

I am using drupal 7, nginx with SSL, php-fpm to serve static pages. I would like to get the maximum security & speed from my nginx installation. Thats why I have decided to install it from source and leave unnecessary modules. can someone help me to select the modules please?  here is what i am choosing...

> ./configure --user=nginx --group=nginx --prefix=/etc/nginx
>   --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-pcre --without-http_uwsgi_module --without-http_scgi_module --without-http_autoindex_module --without-http_ssi_module --add-module=pagespeed

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced that fewer modules makes for a "faster speed" or "better security" ... smaller install size, certainly.

Comment: well, what would you do in this situation?

Comment: I'd just use the defaults and add anything you know you might need, like --with-http_ssl_module . Here's a list of what phusion passenger uses: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/blob/master/bin/passenger-install-nginx-module#L506